# Not displaying select results from dynamic SQL within Cursor

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures, cursor, dynamic-sql

I'm currently learning SQL and trying to think of exercises for myself and I can't seem to make this one work even though it seems simple:

I'm trying to run a cursor through all the filtered tables within my db so that then I could pass that table name to a variable which will be used within a DynamicSQL inside the cursor. The end result should be all values from every column that has the column 'empid' in them. 
However, the message returns as "Commands completed successfully" but I get to see no results despite my select statement.

I'm trying to run something like this:

```
    declare @tablename nvarchar(200);
declare @empid int;
declare @sql nvarchar(200) = N'select * from ' + @tablename + N' where empid = ' +@empid;
declare tablecursor cursor for select table_name from information_schema.tables where col_length(table_name, 'empid') is not null;
open tablecursor;
fetch next from tablecursor into @tablename;
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin 
execute sp_executesql @sql, 825
fetch next from tablecursor into @tablename;
end
close tablecursor;
deallocate tablecursor;
```

I've been searching everywhere for answers to make this work but can't find anything. I've tried putting into a stored procedure and then executing it from there but that didn't work either.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't post an image of your code; paste the code as text. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50507541/edit) your question with your code. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I am completely aware that this leaves my code open to SQL Injections; however, I've very recently learnt about Dynamic SQL and about its dangers and I'm still searching the web for a comprehensive course on how to defend against SQL Injections. If you've got any materials for me, I'm very keen to learn and improve myself.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @SQL Should be outside  but assigning the Variable inside the while loop

```
SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName
```

Should be in while loop.

The other thing is to increase the length of @SQL Variable.

Comment: That is **wide open** to SQL Injection.

Comment: Dear @Larnu, you are absolutely true that it is open for SQL injection but for the current time being that he started learning and want to understand the what is the cause that result is not coming so I explained that. but you are true next time onward i will put a warning as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you kindly for the help. After I listened to your advice I've encountered more errors but at least for these I was able to find answers online. What I also learnt is that you can't have your sql string in quotes when you execute it as that will make SSMS treat @SQL as an actual string and not a variable. I've managed to get it working and my code now looks something like this:

```
create proc cdr @empid nvarchar(5) as

declare @tablename nvarchar(200);

declare tablecursor cursor for select table_name from information_schema.tables where col_length(table_name, 'empid') is not null;

open tablecursor;

fetch next from tablecursor into @tablename;

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

while @@fetch_status = 0

begin

set @sql = N'select * from ' + @tablename + N' where empid = ' + @empid;

execute sp_executesql @sql

fetch next from tablecursor into @tablename;

end

close tablecursor;

deallocate tablecursor;
```